# Add button to create new container with three boxes in it and continue numbing using JQuery

Tags: jquery

1. Create 3 containers with 3 boxes in each of them.
2. Each container is labeled 1,2,3.
3. Each box is labeled 1,2,3…9.
4. Each box also has a caption "I'm in container {x}" where x is the number of the container.
5. There's a "+" button which adds one extra container when clicked and labels it appropriately as 4,5,6...
6. The boxes are to be draggable and droppable between containers. Say, when the box is moved from container 1 to 3, the box caption should change to "I'm in container 3".
7. The boxes should always be stacked neatly in the containers without any empty spaces between them (say, when a box is removed from one container and added to another).
8. No limit on number of containers that can be added.
9. No limit on number of boxes per container.

I have done some of them but some I have no idea in how to do 5,6, and 7..

```js
$("#append").click(function(){
var str = $("h3").text();

 $('.box').append("<div class='column'>7</div><div class='column'>7</div><div class='column'>7</div><h3>C4</h3>");
});
```

```css
.container { border 1px solid red; }
.column { border: 1px solid blue; float:left; width: 30%; text-align:center; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
<div class="container">
    <div class="column">i am container 1</div>
    <div class="column">i am container 2</div>
    <div class="column"> i am container 3</div>
    <h3>
C1
</h3>
</div>
<div class="container">

    <div class="column">i am container 4</div>
    <div class="column">i am container 5</div>
    <div class="column">i am container 6</div>
    <h3>
    C2
    </h3>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="column">i am container 7</div>
    <div class="column">i am container 8</div>
    <div class="column">i am container 9</div>
   <h3>
   C3
   </h3>
</div>
</div>
<br/>

<div class="row">
<button id="append">
Add 
</button>

</div>
```

Comment: So where did you get stuck, what help do you need? And what should happen to an empty 'container' element?

Comment: I stuck in 5, 6 and 7.. when click button it appends container with three boxes but labeling is not correct. Second, how to make any box draggable where a box can be moved  to another container  and change its label  according to its new place

Comment: @Smart: 6. (and 7, i believe) https://jqueryui.com/draggable/ 5. Count current columns, first, then append - content of append param could/should be variable...

Comment: if you click add button, it will add new container with three boxes but label of box should be 10, 11, 12 and not 7,7,7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've mentioned great jQuery UI library for achieving 6. and 7. Here is help for 5.

You have to keep *current HTML structure* for all this to works properly. I have just removed unnecesary and non-semantic br tag from code. Few things must be done: [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), counting of current columns, appending of variable values.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.append', function(){ //event delegation

total=$(this).parent().prev().find('.container').children('.column').length; // get total number of columns, selector is long, but, you start from button, get its parent div, get prev() element, which is container, count children 
$('.box').append('<div class="container"></div>'); //append container 
for(i=total+1;i<total+4;i++) {
 $('.container').last().append("<div class='column'>i am container"+i+"</div>"); // append 3 columns to LAST container with labels
}
 $('.container').last().append('<h3>C'+(total+3)/3+'</h3>'); //append h3 with label
});
```

```css
.container { border 1px solid red; }
.column { border: 1px solid blue; float:left; width: 30%; text-align:center; }

.row {
  clear:both;

}
.append {
  margin-top:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
<div class="container">
    <div class="column">i am container 1</div>
    <div class="column">i am container 2</div>
    <div class="column"> i am container 3</div>
    <h3>
C1
</h3>
</div>
<div class="container">

    <div class="column">i am container 4</div>
    <div class="column">i am container 5</div>
    <div class="column">i am container 6</div>
    <h3>
    C2
    </h3>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="column">i am container 7</div>
    <div class="column">i am container 8</div>
    <div class="column">i am container 9</div>
   <h3>
   C3
   </h3>
</div>
</div>


<div class="row">
<button class="append">
Add 
</button>

</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am sure there is a reason - but the total selector seems awfully long - given that al its doing is counting the number of elements with the class of 'column'. Surely this would do the same? ...total=$('.column').length;... in which case it totals all .column elements in the dom - irrespective of the parents / sibilings. I tested it in your snippet and it seems to work as expected.

Comment: @gavgrif, yes, you are right, i've used it if there are multiple .box divs (main container), but now, after re-reading question... that's maybe not the case... :) If just one .box is on the page, of course that simple selector is better. :)